# Fatal: (vsim-3807) Types do not match between component and entity for port "out1" Without Identifiable Cause

Tags: vhdl, quartus

I've read all the other questions asked with the same issue, but none of them were helpful. Either not enough information was given and so the question remained unanswered, or the answers didn't apply to my case. I'm getting this error (as shown below) and I can't figure out what is causing it.

```
# vsim -novopt -c -t 1ps -L fiftyfivenm -L altera -L altera_mf -L 220model -L sgate -L altera_lnsim work.demultiplexer_vhd_vec_tst 

# Start time: 19:44:15 on Apr 10,2023

# Loading std.standard

# Loading std.textio(body)

# Loading ieee.std_logic_1164(body)

# Loading work.demultiplexer_vhd_vec_tst(demultiplexer_arch)

# Loading ieee.vital_timing(body)

# Loading ieee.vital_primitives(body)

# Loading fiftyfivenm.fiftyfivenm_atom_pack(body)

# Loading fiftyfivenm.fiftyfivenm_components

# Loading work.demultiplexer(structure)

# ** Fatal: (vsim-3807) Types do not match between component and entity for port "out1".

# Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /demultiplexer_vhd_vec_tst/i1 File: LabNine.vho Line: 39

# FATAL ERROR while loading design

# Error loading design

# End time: 19:44:15 on Apr 10,2023, Elapsed time: 0:00:00

# Errors: 1 Warnings: 0

Error
```

Here is the code in question:

```
ENTITY demultiplexer IS
    PORT (  out1 : OUT BIT_VECTOR (0 TO 7); 
            out2 : OUT BIT_VECTOR (0 TO 7); 
            out3 : OUT BIT_VECTOR (0 TO 7); 
            CLR : OUT BIT; 
            inbus : IN BIT_VECTOR(0 TO 7); 
            S0 : IN BIT; S1 : IN BIT);
END demultiplexer;

ARCHITECTURE dataflow OF demultiplexer IS
BEGIN
process(S0, S1)
    BEGIN
        IF (S0 = '0') and (S1 = '0') THEN
            CLR <= '1';
        ELSIF (S0 = '1') and (S1 = '0') THEN
            out1(0) <= inbus(0);
            out1(1) <= inbus(1);
            out1(2) <= inbus(2);
            out1(3) <= inbus(3);
            out1(4) <= inbus(4);
            out1(5) <= inbus(5);
            out1(6) <= inbus(6);
            out1(7) <= inbus(7);
            CLR <= '0';
        ELSIF (S0 = '0') and (S1 = '1') THEN
            out2(0) <= inbus(0);
            out2(1) <= inbus(1);
            out2(2) <= inbus(2);
            out2(3) <= inbus(3);
            out2(4) <= inbus(4);
            out2(5) <= inbus(5);
            out2(6) <= inbus(6);
            out2(7) <= inbus(7);
            CLR <= '0';
        ELSIF (S0 = '1') and (S1 = '1') THEN
            out3(0) <= inbus(0);
            out3(1) <= inbus(1);
            out3(2) <= inbus(2);
            out3(3) <= inbus(3);
            out3(4) <= inbus(4);
            out3(5) <= inbus(5);
            out3(6) <= inbus(6);
            out3(7) <= inbus(7);
            CLR <= '0';
        END IF;
    END process;
END dataflow;
```

In the waveform file, the variables' transitions are set to occur every:

S0 = 50ns

S1 = 100ns

inbus[0] = 200ns

inbus[1] = 400ns

inbus[2] = 800ns

inbus[3] = 1600ns

inbus[4] = 3200ns

inbus[5] = 6400ns

inbus[6] = 12800ns

inbus[7] = 25600ns

And the end time is set to 51200ns

And here is the LabNine.vho file, with the line in question:

```
ARCHITECTURE structure OF demultiplexer IS

SIGNAL gnd : std_logic := '0';

SIGNAL vcc : std_logic := '1';

SIGNAL unknown : std_logic := 'X';

SIGNAL devoe : std_logic := '1';

SIGNAL devclrn : std_logic := '1';

SIGNAL devpor : std_logic := '1';

SIGNAL ww_devoe : std_logic;

SIGNAL ww_devclrn : std_logic;

SIGNAL ww_devpor : std_logic;

SIGNAL ww_out1 : std_logic_vector(0 TO 7);

SIGNAL ww_out2 : std_logic_vector(0 TO 7);

SIGNAL ww_out3 : std_logic_vector(0 TO 7);

SIGNAL ww_CLR : std_logic;

SIGNAL ww_inbus : std_logic_vector(0 TO 7);

SIGNAL ww_S0 : std_logic;

SIGNAL ww_S1 : std_logic;

SIGNAL \out1[7]~output_o\ : std_logic;

SIGNAL \out1[6]~output_o\ : std_logic;

SIGNAL \out1[5]~output_o\ : std_logic;

SIGNAL \out1[4]~output_o\ : std_logic;

SIGNAL \out1[3]~output_o\ : std_logic;

SIGNAL \out1[2]~output_o\ : std_logic;

SIGNAL \out1[1]~output_o\ : std_logic;

SIGNAL \out1[0]~output_o\ : std_logic;

SIGNAL \out2[7]~output_o\ : std_logic;

SIGNAL \out2[6]~output_o\ : std_logic;

SIGNAL \out2[5]~output_o\ : std_logic;

SIGNAL \out2[4]~output_o\ : std_logic;

SIGNAL \out2[3]~output_o\ : std_logic;

SIGNAL \out2[2]~output_o\ : std_logic;

SIGNAL \out2[1]~output_o\ : std_logic;

SIGNAL \out2[0]~output_o\ : std_logic;

SIGNAL \out3[7]~output_o\ : std_logic;

SIGNAL \out3[6]~output_o\ : std_logic;

SIGNAL \out3[5]~output_o\ : std_logic;

SIGNAL \out3[4]~output_o\ : std_logic;

SIGNAL \out3[3]~output_o\ : std_logic;

SIGNAL \out3[2]~output_o\ : std_logic;

SIGNAL \out3[1]~output_o\ : std_logic;

SIGNAL \out3[0]~output_o\ : std_logic;

...
```

Any and all help is appreciated! If you're curious about the lab names, the lab has already happened, and the demultiplexer worked perfectly during the physical demonstration with the DE10-Lite board. Which is why I'm even more perplexed at why it is having an issue now, for the simulation.

Comment: See [ask] Help others reproduce the problem • DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.—copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: fixed, sorry about that.

Comment: you appear to be using a feature of quartus that requires the use of std_logic based types for automated testbench generation compatibility. The Verror lookup for vsim-3807 is "vsim Message # 3807: The type of the port on the entity does not match the type of the port on the component which instantiates it." Either use std_logic based types or write your own testbench.

Comment: So, are you saying that my data types need changing, or there's a library I need to import to make this less error-prone?

Comment: You don't show where the demultiplexer component is instantiated. The error message says there are type mismatches between the component and the entity. It can only be fixed by changing the entity and its architecture(s) or the code trying to instantiate it. You don't show the latter. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: I don't have any other code involved besides what I've posted.

Comment: And you still haven't posted enough information to replicate the problem explained in the error message.

Comment: oh...shoot you're right. I'm editing it in now.

Comment: The process should have inbus in the sensitivity list. A [handwritten testbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VLa3.jpg) can be simple and portable between tools [here ghdl and gtkwave simulating the testbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/my7Uu.jpg)). Otherwise you'd need to change from bit based types to std_logic based types in the demultiplexer design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite not being used by the waveform simulator in any way, you *have* to have the pin assignments laid out (and done correctly) in order for the simulation to actually work.